# Can I switch between files while setting environments using react-native-dotenv?

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am using different `googel-services.json` files for development and production environments on the same project. How can I switch between then while setting the environment using react-native-dotenv package?

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-dotenv` maintainer here! I recommend you create 2 files: `.env.production` and `.env.development` and then use the values where you configure your Firebase instance. I'm going to take the example from the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object):

```js
import {API_KEY, PROJECT_ID, SENDER_ID, APP_ID, MEASUREMENT_ID} from "@env"

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: API_KEY,
  authDomain: `${PROJECT_ID}.firebaseapp.com`,
  databaseURL: `https://${PROJECT_ID}.firebaseio.com`,
  projectId: PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: `${PROJECT_ID}.appspot.com`,
  messagingSenderId: SENDER_ID,
  appId: APP_ID,
  measurementId: `G-${MEASUREMENT_ID}`,
};
```